# How do I create a wireless access point using only one wireless NIC but 2 different SSID:s?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, netplan, wireless-access-point

I would like to create a wireless access point using only one wireless NIC but having 2 different SSID:s, is this even possible? It would be perfect if clients connecting to the different SSID:s also could be directed to different VLAN:s.

What I would like to achieve is something like this: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1607/

I tried multiple configurations on Ubuntu Server using Netplan but without luck.

To create an ordinary access point works fine. It also works to create multiple SSID:s when using multiple NIC:s, but only one for each NIC, and I need 2 SSID:s for each NIC.

This is my setup:

**Output of `lsb_release -a`:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

**Relevant output of `lspci`:**

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA986x/988x 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that to achieve this you don't use netplan but rather hostapd. Hostapd supports virtual SSID:s and VLAN assignments using attributes from a RADIUS-server. The attributes involved are:

- Tunnel-Type = VLAN
- Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
- Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = 1)

The "Tunnel-Private-Group-ID" controls what VLAN the client will be connected to. The RADIUS server can be configured to return different ID:s depending on what the attribute "nas_identifier" is set to in hostapd.conf. The identifier is included in the request to the RADIUS-server. Each virtual access point should have it's own unique string configured for the attribute "nas_identifier".